# Conditional count Measure

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have data looking like this:

```
| ID |OpID|
| -- | -- |
| 10 | 1  |
| 10 | 2  |
| 10 | 4  |
| 11 |null|
| 12 | 3  |
| 12 | 4  |
| 13 | 1  |
| 13 | 2  |
| 13 | 3  |
| 14 | 2  |
| 14 | 4  |
```

Here OpID 4 means 1 and 2.

I would like to count the different occurrences of 1, 2 and 3 in OpID of distinct ID.
If the counts of OpID having **1** would be 4, **2** would be 4, **3** would be 2.

If ID has OpID of 4 but already has data of 1, 2 it wouldn't be counted. But if 4 exists and only 1 (2) is there, count for 2 (1) would be incremented.

The expected output would be:

```
|OpID|Count|
| 1  |  4  |
| 2  |  4  |
| 3  |  2  |
```

(Going to be using the results in a column chart)

Hope this makes sense...

*edit: there are other columns too and an ID and OpID can be duplicated hence need to do a groupby clause before.*

Comment: Can you show the expected out in the form of table..?... As it will be much better than putting in words.

Comment: Sure. I have updated it. Thanks for the suggestion